# timedefined listed options in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, dynamically-generated

I've made a program that's meant to run in the background once it's correctly adjusted(**Me.Hide()**).

It's added a feature that allows the user to select a time once the program-window is supposed to appear(**Me.Show()**) on the screen again.
I want this program to generate a list that contains a few options for when the program is supposed to appear.

*newTime1 = time.ToString(format) + 5min* **and**
*newTime2 = time.ToString(format) + 1hr.*

This is my code, at this point, which adds two options, both of which write the current time:

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim format As String = "HH:mm"
Dim newTime1 As String = time.ToString(format)
Dim newTime2 As String = time.ToString(format) 
With stopTime
    With .Items
        .Add(newTime1)
        .Add(newTime2)
    End With
End With
```

**Edit**

Question: How can I make this program generate a list which adds a generated (HH:mm) value to the options within the combobox; example: option 1(newTime1) is supposed to be time now + 5min and so on.

The combobox is supposed to have a generated list like this if the computertime is 18:00:

18:05

18:00

19:00

Comment: so what is the question?  you cant have two stop times, the user will have to pick one from the list

Comment: I want the program to generate a list within the combobox based upon the current time. In this example it's supposed to add; example; 17:44 and 18:39

Comment: thats a bad idea because if the phone rings, the +5min value may already have lapsed by time the user returns.  Better to use "5 mins from now", "1 hr from now".  But what is your **question**?

Comment: please excuse my bad language. I edited the question, hope it's more informative and describing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now

ComboBox1.Items.Clear
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)))
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Add(New TimeSpan(1, 5, 0)))
```

If these are then used to set the stoptime, allow for the fact that one or more **may already have expired** by then.  It would be better to build a list of text "5mins from Now", "30 mins from now", "1 Hour from now", and set the stop time based on the selection and the **current** time.  That list would be STATIC and never have to be rebuilt, using explicit times, it will have to be rebuilt over and over.

---

To format it:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)).ToString("HH:mm"))
```

Comment: thank you, thats almost perfect! Is there a simple way to convert the datetime into HH:mm without creating new variables?

Comment: just like you have in your code or the previous question - see edit

Comment: That works like a charm! thank you so much :) sorry that I'm bad at explaining, hehe, have a great eve!